# How to format email message in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, mailkit

I have a template.docx file, which has a Table, indented words to the left and right sides, some paragraphs of text, etc. I want to retain that structure when sending a message. At the moment, it parses the content properly, but doesn't format it.

Code:

```
public async Task SendEmail(User receiver)
    {
        var user = "...@mail.com";
        var password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EMAIL_PASSWORD");

        string emailTemplateFilePath = "..path..\\template.docx";

        // Load the Word document template
        using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(emailTemplateFilePath, false))
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(user));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(receiver.FullName, receiver.EmailAddress));
            message.Subject = "Subject";

            var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();

            // Read the content of the Word document template with OpenXmlReader
            using (var reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Paragraph))
                    {
                        var paragraph = (Paragraph)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
                        string paragraphText = string.Join("", paragraph.Descendants<Text>().Select(t => t.Text));

                        bodyBuilder.TextBody += paragraphText + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Table))
                    {
                        var table = (Table)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
                        foreach (var row in table.Descendants<TableRow>())
                        {
                            var rowText = "";
                            foreach (var cell in row.Descendants<TableCell>())
                            {
                                rowText += string.Join("", cell.Descendants<Text>().Select(t => t.Text)) + "\t";
                            }

                            bodyBuilder.TextBody += rowText.TrimEnd('\t') + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            // Send the email using MailKit
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("host", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(user, password);
                await client.SendAsync(message);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

The table looks like this:
[image: Table]

Template File:

[image: Template]

Comment: Probably your best option is to create an HTML template as opposed to using a Word document so you can ensure the formatting is correct. The downside is that you have to produce the HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change or convert your template to html file instead of docx. In this way you can preserve your format.

## For System.Web.Mail

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
message.Body = <content here>
```

## For System.Net.Mail

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = <content here>
```

If you would like to replace some values in your template, you can use [HandlerBar](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net)

For System.Net.Mail, you can explore [AlternateViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews?view=net-7.0) in case some recipients can't render html format.